# Can not get table header elements

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

In Python, I have a variable containing an `html` table element obtained like this:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.myPage.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
table = tree.xpath('//table[@class="list"]')
```

The `table` variable has this content:

```
<table class="list">
      <tr>
        <th>Date(s)</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Location</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jan 18-31</td>
        <td>Tennis</td>
        <td><a href="tennis-grand-slam/australian-open/index.htm">Australia Open</a></td>
        <td>Melbourne, Australia</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to extract the headers like this:

```
rows = iter(table)
headers = [col.text for col in next(rows)]
print "headers are: ", headers
```

However, when I print the `headers` variable I get this:

```
headers are:  ['\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n
      ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n
', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n        ', '\n
        ', '\n        ', '\n        ']
```

How can I extract the headers properly?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem using [this code](https://gist.github.com/har07/c693eac57c79c2896881f9b6e2de2202). Could you post simplified but complete codes to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
from lxml import html

HTML_CODE = """<table class="list">
      <tr>
        <th>Date(s)</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Location</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jan 18-31</td>
        <td>Tennis</td>
        <td><a href="tennis-grand-slam/australian-open/index.htm">Australia Open</a></td>
        <td>Melbourne, Australia</td>
      </tr>
</table>"""

tree = html.fromstring(HTML_CODE)
headers = tree.xpath('//table[@class="list"]/tr/th/text()')
print "Headers are: {}".format(', '.join(headers))
```

**Output:**

```
Headers are: Date(s), Sport, Event, Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the  table and presuming there is only one:

```
table[0].xpath("//th/text()")
```

Or if you just want the headers from the table and don't plan on using it for anything else you just need:

```
headers = tree.xpath('//table[@class="list"]//th/text()')
```

Both will give you:

```
['Date(s)', 'Sport', 'Event', 'Location']
```